# Does anyone know why I would be getting this error with using "import pybulletgym"

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

[Code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU9VI.png)

I have installed pybullet in my terminal in my VMware Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine and on windows and I get this error message on both. If you see an error that I could be making please let me know. Pretty new to using pybullet so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed pybulletgym? e.g. with `pip install pybulletgym`, or an Ubuntu package if they provide one?

Comment: In the future please post code and errors as text though, e.g. copy and paste it and format it correctly (the {} button for code) rather than post it as images. We can put images inline in the question, but I'm not sure it's worth showing that image without cropping it down to show the code readably in the space we've got.

Comment: @Rup when I try that in both terminals no packages are found? Also will do regarding posting code as text.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like that isn’t available through pip after all. You’ll have to download the code from github and build it and install it. Instructions here: https://github.com/benelot/pybullet-gym/blob/master/README.md#installing-pybullet-gym

Comment: @Rup I have done that in the past but do not understand what that means. Now when I enter the first line into the VMware terminal (sorta gave up on windows a while ago) I get the error `fatal: destination path 'gym' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: @Rup I followed the steps and reinstalled it but the code still does not work.